# MySQL: gets all of procedure out parameter null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

It seems like the "select into" isn't working with the following code.
I can get data from "select clause" from sql query but with test procedure code, it only returns null value for every out parameter. (There's one record should be returned)

Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

OS: Mac OSX
DBM: MySQL WorkBench 6.1
MySQL: 5.6.13

**Procedure Code**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER= PROCEDURE `POLL_NEW_MESSAGE`(OUT DEVICEID INT, OUT ORGID INT, OUT MSGDATE VARCHAR(8), OUT MSGTIME VARCHAR(6), OUT BODY TEXT, OUT TOKEN VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    DECLARE DEVICEID INT        DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE ORGID INT           DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE MSGDATE VARCHAR(8)  DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE MSGTIME VARCHAR(6)  DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE BODY TEXT           DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE TOKEN VARCHAR(64)   DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE UPDATED INT         DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT msg.device_id, msg.org_id, msg.msg_date, msg.msg_time, msg.body
    INTO DEVICEID, ORGID, MSGDATE, MSGTIME, BODY
    FROM pm_msg msg, pm_org org
    WHERE msg.status = '0'
        AND org.org_id = msg.org_id
        AND org.status = 'G';

END
```

**Test Code1**

```
PREPARE s FROM ' CALL `POLL_NEW_MESSAGE`(@DEVICEID, @ORGID, @MSGDATE, @MSGTIME, @BODY, @TOKEN)';
execute s;
SELECT @DEVICEID, @ORGID, @MSGDATE, @MSGTIME, @BODY, @TOKEN;
```

**Test Code2**

```
CALL `POLL_NEW_MESSAGE`(@DEVICEID, @ORGID, @MSGDATE, @MSGTIME, @BODY, @TOKEN);SELECT @DEVICEID, @ORGID, @MSGDATE, @MSGTIME, @BODY, @TOKEN;
```

Comment: Call it directly without `prepare statement`

Comment: @Rahul, I also tried but same result. `CALL `POLL_NEW_MESSAGE`(@DEVICEID, @ORGID, @MSGDATE, @MSGTIME, @BODY, @TOKEN);SELECT @DEVICEID, @ORGID, @MSGDATE, @MSGTIME, @BODY, @TOKEN;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring out parameter within procedure with same variables names caused the problem.
Once I remove all declaration of variables which are already used as out parameter of procedure, it works as supposed to.

**Fixed code**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER= PROCEDURE `POLL_NEW_MESSAGE`(OUT DEVICEID INT, OUT ORGID INT, OUT MSGDATE VARCHAR(8), OUT MSGTIME VARCHAR(6), OUT BODY TEXT)
BEGIN

    SELECT msg.device_id, msg.org_id, msg.msg_date, msg.msg_time, msg.body
    INTO DEVICEID, ORGID, MSGDATE, MSGTIME, BODY
    FROM pm_msg msg, pm_org org
    WHERE msg.status = '0'
        AND org.org_id = msg.org_id
        AND org.status = 'G'
        LIMIT 1;

END
```

Comment: Even though this will solve the issue of getting NULL values but think for a moment ... the way you are doing .. you will end up getting wrong result cause you have declared the OUT variables as scalar. See my answer, I have pointed out the same.

Comment: @Rahul: So long as the `where` fetches a single row result, the solution is fine. Otherwise, without a limit clause last row values would be assigned to `OUT` parameters.

Comment: @Ravinder, that's the point here `So long as` which can't be guaranteed (non - deterministic). `LIMIT` is not the solution rather a pointer. Suggesting him to use TVP as OUT parameter which will get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared all your `OUT` variables as `scalar` type but in your `select into` query you are trying to make them store multiple values. The way you are doing .. you will end up getting wrong result cause you have declared the OUT variables as scalar. So, if your query returns multiple rows then you will definitely end up getting wrong result.

```
SELECT msg.device_id, msg.org_id, msg.msg_date, msg.msg_time, msg.body
INTO DEVICEID, ORGID, MSGDATE, MSGTIME, BODY
FROM pm_msg msg, pm_org org
WHERE msg.status = '0'
    AND org.org_id = msg.org_id
    AND org.status = 'G'
    LIMIT 1;
```

Suggestion is, have a table valued parameter as OUT parameter.

Comment: `NULL` output was not due to lack of `LIMIT` or multi row resultset. It is because of ambiguity in names defined. See: [*answer by handicop*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23902705/767881)

Comment: @Ravinder, Yes saw it. I don't mean it was the reason for the issue but rather flaw in his solution.

Comment: @Rahul, Thanks for your comment, yes, I added limit 1 in the select as well

Answer (score 0):

Name of declared parameter inside stored procedure has to be UNIQUE.
(Note: these names are case insensitive)
Even if name of declared parameter is same as column name from table, it returns NULL.